# A nicer proof of Lagrange's 'best approximations' law?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $p_N/q_N$ be the $N^\text{th}$ convergent of the continued fraction for some irrational number $\alpha$. It turns out that for any other approximation $p/q$ (with $q \le q_N$) which isn't a convergent $|\alpha q - p| > |\alpha q_{N-1} - p_{N-1}|$. I'm wondering if there are any nice proofs for this result?

---

In my book this is proved by picking $x,y$ that solves

$$
\begin{pmatrix} p_N & p_{N-1} \\ q_N & q_{N-1} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} p \\ q \end{pmatrix}
$$

since $x$ and $y$ have opposite sign, as well as $\alpha q_N - p_N$ and $\alpha q_{N-1} - p_{N-1}$ have opposite sign we can conclude that $|\alpha q - p| = |x (\alpha q_N - p_N) + y (\alpha q_{N-1} - p_{N-1})| = |x| |\alpha q_N - p_N| + |y| |\alpha q_{N-1} - p_{N-1}|$ which proves the theorem.

I am looking for different proofs than this one.

Comment: This looks like an excellent self-contained proof. What's not nice about it? :-) (What book is this, BTW?) (I just looked up how this is proved in Khinchin's book… while his theorem is more general—α need not be irrational, and p/q is allowed to be a convergent as well—the proof relies on a couple of previous theorems, and I wouldn't call it "nicer". I can quote it if you like.)

Comment: This is from the book *Exploring the Number Jungle* by Edward Burger (It's a really good book!). I just got the idea that this result has probably been proven in all kinds of different ways and I hope to see some of the best.

Comment: The statement of the theorem says  is an irrational number, but I do not see anywhere in the proof we use that, so does the theorem applies to all real numbers ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course there is a nicer proof! In fact, it's almost obvious if one thinks about geometric interpretation of continued fraction: consider the line $y=\alpha x$; then the best approximation (i.e. approximation that minimizes $|\alpha q-p|=q|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}|$) is the point of integer lattice nearest to this line; finally observe that convergents with even/odd numbers of the continued fraction give coordinates of [verices of] the convex hull of [points of] lattice lying over/under the line.

---

One can also (as [J. M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498) suggests) take a look at *Lorentzen, Waadeland. Continued Fractions with Applications*, I.2.1 (esp. figure 1 and the text near it; there are no words "convex hull" there but implicitly everything is explained, more or less).

Upd. One more reference is Davenport's "The Higher Arithmetics" (section IV.12).

---

Finally, an illustration (from Arnold's book).

- Bold line $y=\alpha x$ (on the picture $\alpha=\frac{10}7$) is approximated by vectors $e_i$ corresponding to convergents (namely, $e_i$ ends at $(p_i,q_i)$);
- each vector (starting from $e_3$) is a linear combination of two preciding ones: $e_{i+2}=e_i+a_{i-1}e_{i+1}$, where $a$ is the maximal integer s.t. the new vector still doesn't intersect the line;
- this is exactly the algorithm for representing $\alpha$ by a continued fraction: $\alpha=[a_0,a_1,\dots]$.

[image: geometry of continued fractions]

Comment: Probably I should add that I've learnt this from V.Arnold's book [continued fractions](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/mmmf-lectures/book.14.pdf) (in Russian).

Comment: This is also in Lorentzen and Waadeland's "Continued Fractions with Applications" ; a nice book, if you can get to read it.

Comment: I like the sound of this but I haven't been able to understand it yet

Comment: To expand on my comment: there is a nice illustration of "best approximation" on an integer lattice on p. 12, and a short proof of Lagrange's on p. 408.

Comment: More or less, that's actually why I remembered the book in the first place... (though my interests in the book are in different chapters) :) But the lattice picture is convincing enough I suppose.

Comment: Nice pic Grigory, did you scan it or redraw the whole thing? :)

Comment: Thanks for the picture; it really clarifies many things about continued fractions. I wonder why not every book contains it!

Comment: This is a nice picture, but it doesn't convince me of anything. _Why_ do the vertices of the convex hulls correspond to the convergents? Why not some other rational approximation?

Comment: This answer is missing some crucial details. The convex hull of the set of all convergents to $\alpha$ is a half-infinite parallelogram containing the line $y = \alpha x$. [In your picture, this would be the region bounded by the lines $y = -x$, $y = 10x/7+1$, and $y=10(x-1)/7$.]