# formula for converting a very long number to a fraction

Tags: arithmetic, average

What is the average (arithmetic mean) of 8, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, and 2?

the answer is $4\frac{6}{7}$.

The sum of numbers is 34 and when you divide by 7 it's 4.8571428.....

How can I get the fraction of above number?

Comment: I think the Answer is already embedded in your Question.  The "fraction" is $34/7$, which can be rewritten as $4 \; 6/7$, a so-called "mixed fraction".  Perhaps your Question is more about converting a decimal expansion back to an improper or a mixed fraction?

Comment: exactly, I need that . .

Comment: Not possible, at least exactly, unless you know how many numbers you are averaging, and you know the decimal average with infinite precision. If you do, then you can multiply the average by the number of items being averaged to recover their sum, then perform long division to get a quotient and remainder. And this assumes you started with integers in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

A decimal expansion can be converted to a sequence of [best rational approximations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81894/convergent-of-continued-fractions-the-best-rational-approximation-of-a-number) by an application of [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).

The basic idea is to subtract off the integer part, and then reciprocate the fractional part.  The result will have a nonzero integer part, and the process can be continued until the fractional part is zero (or forever, if the number is not rational).

Here we take the following steps, ignoring for the sake of illustration the "dot..dot..dot" portions of the number:

$x_0 = 4 + 0.8571428...$

$x_1 = 1/0.8571428 = 1 + 0.16666674444...$

$x_2 = 1/0.16666674444 = 5 + 0.99999720016...$

Notice that this $x_2$ is very nearly $6$, suggesting that if full precision had been used we would get exactly $6$ and the process would halt there.

Putting the pieces together we have $4 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{6}} = 4 \; \frac{6}{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to multiply the decimal by the denominator and round.  You have $ 0.857128 \cdot 7 = 5.9999996$, so the fraction is $\frac 67$  Works great if you know the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't we missing something here? Surely $34/7$ is a repeating decimal, as the "$857142$" after the decimal point repeats indefinitely. Using high school math we denote $x=4.857142...$ and $10^6x=4857142.857142...$. Subtracting $10^6x-x=999,999x=4857138$. so, the fraction the OP is looking for is $4857138/999999$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what youre looking for.. 
8+7+7+5+3+2+2=34

Since theres 7 numbers =

(34 over 7) 34/7 =

(Four and six sevenths) 4 6/7